# Question about proof of finding Aut$(\Bbb Z_{10})$

Tags: abstract-algebra

The question I have is from one line in this proof:

To begin with, observe that once
we know $\alpha(1)$, we know $\alpha(k)$ for any $k$, because $\alpha(k) = k\alpha(1)$.

So, we need only determine the choices for $\alpha(1)$ that make $\alpha$ an automorphism of $\Bbb Z_{10}$.

**Since for isomorphisms $ |x| = |\alpha(x)|$ for all $x$ in $G$, and in this case $|1| = |\alpha(1)| = 10$, there are four candidates for $\alpha(1): \alpha(1) = 1, \alpha(1) = 3, \alpha(1) = 7, \alpha(1) = 9$.**

Why does the fact that $|\alpha(1)| = 10$ imply these four choices make the automorphism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $|\alpha(1)|=|1|=10$, then necessarily $\alpha$ is bijective. And bijective homomorphisms are isomorphisms (i.e. bijective endomorphisms are automorphisms).

Also, there can be no other automorphisms, because any other choice for $\alpha(1)$ has orders $2,5$ or $0$, which makes $\alpha$ non-bijective.

Comment: So because $|\alpha(1)| = |1| = 10$ and $\alpha(k) = k\alpha(1) = [\alpha(1)]^k$ (change from additive notation to cyclic notation for the last one), if $\alpha(1) = 2,4,5,6,8$, then $k\alpha(1) = [\alpha(1)]^k$ doesn't map to all elements of $\Bbb Z_{10}$?

Comment: Exactly. In the case of $2,4,6,8$ you can't get to any of $1,3,5,7,9$, and in the case of $5$ you only get $5$ and $0$. $\alpha(1)=0$ is even worse.

Answer (score 0):

These are the four generators of $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$. You can check that any other choice fails to generate all of $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$. An isomorphism has to map a generator to a generator.

In general, the generators of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ are the numbers relatively prime to (and less than) $n$.